# Image filtering options on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, image-manipulation, cgimage

I have an application that requires some work on image filters, so I was just wondering what are the options available to me.

I did stumble upon core image in the wwdc videos but I believe it wont work on iOS....?

Google also revealed this project http://code.google.com/p/simple-iphone-image-processing/
but it isnt enough for my needs.

If anyone can guide me on the right direction it would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What sort of image filtering do you need? Presumably you mean actual image processing rather than e.g. selecting an image from a filtered list?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by filtered list.... basically my app is somewhat similar to the instagram app.... we need to apply different filters on the images the user will take from the app. Sepia, black & white etc.....

Comment: No not much... I've searched around a lot & I believe OpenGLES is only option which will fulfill my needs. You can download sample code from apples website for image processing to get you started.

Answer (score 2):

For image filtering, you can use apple filters or third party tool **GPUImage** framework.It will help you.